# I have a problem showing star rating on Ruby on Rails 6 using jquery. Stars dont show up

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

this is the form im using that is where to permit select stars for review.

```
   <%= simple_form_for([@restaurant, @restaurant.reviews.build]) do |f|%>
    <div id="rating-form">
     <%= f.input :rating %>
    </div>

this is the javascript / j query code for the stars
    <script>
        $('#rating-form').raty({
            path: '/assets/',
            scoreName: 'review[rating]'
        });
    </script>
```

i have tried changing the directory, i have all dependencies required, gems. But still cant made them work. Any help, please?